# Scaling a simple api, for half million hits

Tags: database, api, architecture, backend

I have to create an api which will need to handle about 250,000 - 500,000 requests a day, and we have to do a simple write to a sql database for each request.

also the traffic will burst at the peak hours.

What would be the ideal architecture for handling such traffic.

I was thinking that horizontally scaling the backend api and then making the requests to the same database, but I am not sure if that the right way, hence I need some advice

1. Will the database choke with that amount of requests ?
2. So should I shard to increase the throughput ?
3. Do I need to use something like Kafka to make writes asynchronous ?

thank you !

Comment: 250k-500k requests per day does not sound like very much unless they all happen in span of several minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of missing variables here, for example - what database do you have? how complex the query is? to how many machines your service is deployed? and more...

I'd suggest to leave the terminology of 'ideal architecture', and to start using a terminology of trade-offs. First, define what architecture characteristics are important to you:

1. Scalability?
2. Reliability?
3. Availability?
4. Anything else?

After you made the decisions, it will be easier to decide how to build the architecture in light of the characteristics it needs to maintain. I'll give some examples:

1. You might come to decision that it's very important for you that the service will respond very quickly to the client, however writing to the DB is not that urgent and can be done at the end of the day. In this case the service doesn't have to do a DB transaction (which takes a lot of time), but just to write somewhere this request, and send the response to the client (which will be quicker then doing it after DB transaction). Then you'll have also a batch which runs once a day (offline) and writes all the requests to the DB. With this solution your service responds quickly, all the data is written to the DB at once, however there is a gap between these 2 actions. This is the trade-off.
2. You might decide that a batch which runs once a day is not good enough and you'd like to write to the DB more frequently, but still not synchronously on every request to the service, a possible solution for that is an [event-driven architecture](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-driven-architecture.html) - your service will write the requests to a queue (i.e Kafka as you mentioned), and there will be another service that listens to the queue and executes the writing to the DB. Again the first service will respond very quickly because it doesn't execute DB transaction, but what will you do if the second service encounters an exception, after the first service already responded? This is another trade-off.

And of course there are more ways to do that, but the bottom line - there is no an 'ideal' way, only a collection of trade-offs that you need to consider while yo decide what architecture mostly fits the characteristics that you defined.